# How do I render a data property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, data-binding

I have this super basic starting point:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/dictionary.css" />

    <script src="Scripts/kuroshiro.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="searchResultsVue">
        <table>
            <tr v-for="r in results">
                {{ r.Result.ent_seq }}
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>


    <script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
    <script>


        var searchResultsVue = new Vue({
            el: '#searchResultsVue',
            data: { results: [{ Result: { ent_seq: 'asd' } }] }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but I get

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "r" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with HTML's lenient rendering practices. When it's building the Dom elements for a table it's expecting a certain structure and anything deviating from that structure is pushed outside the definitions.

And so

```
    <table>
        <tr v-for="r in results">
            {{ r.Result.ent_seq }}
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Acts like

```
    <table>
        <tr v-for="r in results">
        </tr>
    </table>
    {{ r.Result.ent_seq }}
```

The Error is then that it is seeing the call to the loop variable outside the loop.

[As seen in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6dmzs81q/) Adding a table definition tag around your code stops it from being pushed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your markup. `tr` needs `td` as its child to work properly.

```
<tr v-for="r in results">
  <td>{{ r.Result.ent_seq }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the td tag inside tr.
It seems there is something special about table-rows

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="searchResultsVue">
        <table>
            <tr v-for="r in results">
                <td>{{ r.Result.ent_seq }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>


    <script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        var searchResultsVue = new Vue({
            el: '#searchResultsVue',
            data: { results: [{ Result: { ent_seq: 'asd' } }] }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```